# Using "generated strings" (stringWithFormat) as keys for NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I would like to do something like this:

```
#define GETKEY (a) ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",a])

NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionay=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
//population of dictionary
[mutableDictionary setObject:anObject forKey:GETKEY(someIntValue)];
//... then retrive the object
[mutableDictionary getObjectForKey:GETKEY(someIntValue)];
```

But I'm concerned the stringWithFormat method returns a different instance of NSString with the same value, I mean like having, 2 strings: "0" and another instance with value "0". I would like to know if this **is a safe way to get and set the objects in the dictionary**. If not, **what other way could be the best way to "generate" a key object from an integer?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you're doing is perfectly safe, and will work as expected. The keys of a dictionary when getting and setting are compared using the `isEqual` method, which only checks the values of the strings, and not their addresses. "0" and "0" are equal, regardless of whether they are the same instance or not.

You can read more about the `isEqual` documentation in the [NSObject Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html). Just be aware that `==` and `isEqual` are not the same thing (`==` checks addresses, `isEqual` checks values).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using NSNumber if expect all of them to be numbers but it will work with NSString also. The NSDictionary keys must conform to NSCopying protocol and keys are compared using the isEqual: selector.